# Convert Frozen graph for tfLite for Coral using tflite_convert

Tags: tensorflow, google-coral

I'm using MobileNetV2 and trying to get it working for Google Coral. Everything seems to work except the Coral Web Compiler, throws a random error, `Uncaught application failure`. So I think the problem is the intemidary steps required. For example, I'm using this with tflite_convert

```
tflite_convert \
  --graph_def_file=optimized_graph.pb \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --output_file=mobilenet_v2_new.tflite \
  --inference_type=FLOAT \
  --inference_input_type=FLOAT \
  --input_arrays=input \
  --output_arrays=final_result \
  --input_shapes=1,224,224,3
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is most likely because your model is not [quantized](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantize#quantization-aware-training). Edge TPU devices do not currently support float-based model inference. **For the best results, you should enable quantization during training (described in the link)**. However, you can also apply quantization during TensorFlow Lite conversion.

With post-training quantization, you sacrifice accuracy but can test something out more quickly. When you convert your graph to TensorFlow Lite format, set `inference_type` to `QUANTIZED_UINT8`. You'll also need to apply the quantization parameters (mean/range/std_dev) on the command line as well.

```
tflite_convert \
  --graph_def_file=optimized_graph.pb \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --output_file=mobilenet_v2_new.tflite \
  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --input_arrays=input \
  --output_arrays=final_result \
  --input_shapes=1,224,224,3 \
  --mean_values=128 --std_dev_values=127 \
  --default_ranges_min=0 --default_ranges_max=255
```

You can then pass the quantized `.tflite` file to the [model compiler](https://coral.withgoogle.com/web-compiler/).

For more details on the Edge TPU model requirements, check out [TensorFlow models on the Edge TPU](https://coral.withgoogle.com/tutorials/edgetpu-models-intro/).

Comment: I did get a file to export with slight modification to your suggestion. It won't compile though. This MobileNetV2 is coming from the tensorflow for poets 1/2 guides. Still got a ease of use problem with the Edge TPUs 

tflite_convert   --graph_def_file=optimized_graph.pb   --output_format=TFLITE   --output_file=mobilenet_v2_new.tflite  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8   --input_arrays=input   --output_arrays=final_result   --input_shapes=1,224,224,3 --mean_values=128   --std_dev_values=127 --default_ranges_min=0 --default_ranges_max=255

Comment: This may actually be an issue with the current web compiler, which is very strict about the models it supports. We're looking into this internally.

Comment: We released a new version of the model compiler today, and this updated version should properly compile your quantized model output. I also edited the answer to explain a bit more about pre/post training quantization.

Comment: You're awesome! I did a quick test and the compiler did work as expected. Looking forward to more testing. Thank you

Comment: Coral docs state that "The Edge TPU does not support models built using post-training quantization" [link](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#compatibility-overview)